# How to define a custom loss function for a model with multiple inputs and outputs in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on Keras implementation of an architecture that takes 2 inputs (input_im_low, input_im_high) and passes them separately to one architecture and gets 2 outputs. The network is using a custom loss function defined based on these 2 outputs and the inputs, and there is not any ground truth, as the goal of the training is to reduce the custom loss. I tried to create the loss function according to Keras documentation (https://keras.io/api/losses/), but it doesn't work properly. I wasn't sure if I need to use the add_loss() API, and if yes, how it should be adjusted for my case?

Can anyone advise me how to adjust the loss function?

I get the following error by running the code:

```
    per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the code:

```
# DecomNet - low

input_im_low = Input(shape=[None, None, 3], dtype=tf.float32, name='input_im_low')
input_max_low = tf.reduce_max(input_im_low, axis=3, keepdims=True)
input_im_low_full = concatenate([input_max_low, input_im_low], axis=3)

conv = Conv2D(channel, kernel_size * 3, padding='same', activation=None, name="shallow_feature_extraction_low")(input_im_low_full)
for idx in range(5):
    conv = Conv2D(channel, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu', name='activated_layer_low_%d' % idx)(conv)
conv = Conv2D(4, kernel_size, padding='same', activation=None, name='recon_layer_low')(conv)
out_low = tf.sigmoid(conv)

# DecomNet - High

input_im_high = Input(shape=[None, None, 3], dtype=tf.float32, name='input_im_high')
input_max_high = tf.reduce_max(input_im_high, axis=3, keepdims=True)
input_im_high_full = concatenate([input_max_high, input_im_high], axis=3)

conv = Conv2D(channel, kernel_size * 3, padding='same', activation=None, name="shallow_feature_extraction_high")(input_im_high_full)
for idx in range(5):
    conv = Conv2D(channel, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu', name='activated_layer_high_%d' % idx)(conv)
conv = Conv2D(4, kernel_size, padding='same', activation=None, name='recon_layer_high')(conv)
out_high = tf.sigmoid(conv)

def Decom_loss(out_high, out_low):

    R_low = out_low[:, :, :, 0:3]
    I_low = out_low[:, :, :, 3:4]

    R_high = out_high[:, :, :, 0:3]
    I_high = out_high[:, :, :, 3:4]

    I_low_3 = concatenate([I_low, I_low, I_low], axis=3)
    I_high_3 = concatenate([I_high, I_high, I_high], axis=3)

    # output_R_low = R_low
    # output_I_low = I_low_3

    recon_loss_low = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(R_low * I_low_3 - input_im_low))
    recon_loss_high = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(R_high * I_high_3 - input_im_high))
    recon_loss_mutal_low = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(R_high * I_low_3 - input_im_low))
    recon_loss_mutal_high = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(R_low * I_high_3 - input_im_high))
    equal_R_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(R_low - R_high))

    Ismooth_loss_low = smooth(I_low, R_low)
    Ismooth_loss_high = smooth(I_high, R_high)

    loss_Decom = recon_loss_low + recon_loss_high + 0.001 * recon_loss_mutal_low + 0.001 * recon_loss_mutal_high + 0.1 * Ismooth_loss_low + 0.1 * Ismooth_loss_high + 0.01 * equal_R_loss

    return loss_Decom

model = Model(inputs=[input_im_low, input_im_high], outputs=[out_low, out_high])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=Decom_loss)
model.fit({'input_im_low': train_low_data, 'input_im_high': train_high_data}, epochs=10, batch_size=4)
```

P.S. - A Tensorflow 1.x implementation of this network can be found at https://github.com/weichen582/RetinexNet.

Comment: when you fit, I don't see the target... model.fit({'input1': X1, 'input2': X2}, {'target1': Y1, 'target2': Y2}, ....)

Comment: That's the point, there isn't any target here as we are just comparing the results of two networks.